# quill inserttext list, what format to use

Tags: list, text, quill, bullet

Basically I am trying to get the MarketShare text as a bullet list item only.
All the lines above Marketshare also show as a bullet list.
I struggle to understand what the (0,4) means in this.quill.formatText below.
and using this.quill.format('list',false) doesn't turn it off

The same question I have with regards to setting the size. I would like MarketShare to have a bigger size then the rest using inserttext, but when I use size 20 px as below, it doesn't work.

```html
this.quill.format('list', false);
           this.quill.insertText(0, '\n', '', true)
          
           this.quill.formatText(0,4,'list', true);
           this.quill.insertText(0, 'Marketshare (Max ' +     
 this.globals.MARKETSHAREPOTENTIAL + ' points)', {'size' : '20px', true)
          
         
           this.quill.insertText(0, '\n', '', true)
```

```html
 this.quill.format('list', false);
 this.quill.insertText(0, 'this text must be a bullet list', '', true)
 this.quill.formatText(0,4,'list', true);
   

 
  this.quill.insertText(0, 'this text I like to have in different font size or for instance as header 3 or header 4', 'bold', true)
```

Comment: What is "the MarketShare text"?

Comment: It is just a string, and it shows the text correctly, or do u mean something else?

Comment: Can you include the text you are apply your code to? Also can you use raw strings instead of referring to your application code like `this.globals.MARKETSHAREPOTENTIAL`

Comment: I adapted the lower code snippet to reflect what I want based on some simple text. Hopefully it is more clear now. Let me know if you need more info. Would love to fix this issue, I struggle to understand the info available on this.

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I simply want to know how to use formattext or formatline to get a single line of text as a bullet list item (a dot in front of it) I dont’t want the text below it to be bullet list so after the single line it should stop the bullet list. With the above code, it continues putting bullets in front of all textlines. How do I turn it off again?. And the other text line in a different size font.